# Positioning a JTable

Tags: java, swing, layout

(I speak French so I apologize in advance)

I am stuck with my application. I am trying to properly position a JTable but setPostion or setBound do not work.

This is what I get:
[Picutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyDdH.png)

[image]

I also tried to use layouts but it did not change anything. I also try to set null layout to the JFrame but it caused all content to disappear.

Here is the JTable code:

```
    public class STable
{
    private JTable jTable;
    private Object[][] data;
    private String title[];
    private int x, y;

    public STable(int x, int y)
    {
        //Location
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Object[][] getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(Object[][] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title[])
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public JTable getJTable()
    {
        return this.jTable;
    }

    public JTable createTable()
    {
        this.jTable = new JTable(this.data, this.title);
        this.jTable.setLocation(this.x, this.y);
        return this.jTable;
    }
}
```

And here is my frame:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.app.graphics.panels.MainP;
import com.app.utils.SButton;
import com.app.utils.STable;
import com.app.utils.WindowMover;

public class MainF extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3853419533053844386L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private JPanel currentPanel;
    private MainP panel;

    private SButton exitB, hideB, homeB, userB, settingB;

    private BufferedImage icon;

    public MainF()
    {
        this.setTitle("DAMP");
        this.setContentPane(this.panel = new MainP());
        this.currentPanel = this.panel;

        //Icon
        try
        {
            icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/ressources/icon.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
            { e1.printStackTrace(); }
        this.setIconImage(icon);

        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(1080, 720));

        //Move window
        WindowMover mover = new WindowMover(this);
        this.addMouseListener(mover);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mover);

        Object[][] data = {
                  {"Cysboy", new JButton("6boy"), new Double(1.80), new Boolean(true)},
                  {"BZHHydde", new JButton("BZH"), new Double(1.78), new Boolean(false)},
                  {"IamBow", new JButton("BoW"), new Double(1.90), new Boolean(false)},
                  {"FunMan", new JButton("Year"), new Double(1.85), new Boolean(true)}
                };
        String  title[] = {"Pseudo", "Age", "Taille", "OK ?"};

        STable table = new STable(500, 500);
        table.setTitle(title);
        table.setData(data);
        this.getContentPane().add(table.createTable());

        this.exitB = new SButton(this, "exitM", 1060, 8, true);
        this.hideB = new SButton(this, "hideM", 1037, 16, true);
        this.homeB = new SButton(this, "home", 9, 39, true);
        this.userB = new SButton(this, "user", 7, 610, true);
        this.settingB = new SButton(this, "settings", 7, 670, true);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //Animator.fadeInFrame(this, Animator.FAST);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource().equals(exitB))
            System.exit(0);
        else if(e.getSource().equals(hideB))
            this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
        else if(e.getSource().equals(homeB))
            return;
        else if(e.getSource().equals(settingB))
            return;
        else if(e.getSource().equals(userB))
            return;
    }
}
```

If you have questions do not hesitate to ask. Sorry for any errors.
Sincerely,
Maki!

Comment: Please post a code that can be compiled an run: [MCVE]

Comment: You are using all kinds of custom components which we know nothing about. First try getting your code to work using the default JDK classes. If that works then the problem is your custom components. If it doesn't work then you have a MCVE to post in the forum.

Comment: No, my personal coposant it's just extend main class (SButton -> extends JButton). No other modification. I have already test that.